# How can I have different templates for different sections of my website with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

For not logged in users, I want to use template1, which has it's own CSS, JS, views, etc. For logged in users, I want to use template2. How can I accomplish this with AngularJS?

Comment: almost sounds like you want differnt pages to load from server...unless you plan on loading all the css and js...really not clear what you want

Comment: Yes - I guess I want to load different pages from the server

Comment: If you did want to load all css and js...could add a routeParam for `isLoggedIN` and set templateUrl within config

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand...

Comment: for routes you have would mean adding extra route for each path with extra param `/users` would have `/users/:auth` and set template within that config. Would take some other logic in $routeChangeStart` too i think...was thinking and typing at same time when i suggested it

Comment: Instead of having a single-page app, create a two-pages app. When login succeeds in the first app, change the location to the second app. When logout succeeds in the second app, change the location to the first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out **ui-router**. Not sure this would help. Just try out and see.

With the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you could create multiple templates. A sample page given [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/)